# How to call cascading find() in Meteor + MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I use Meteor & Iron-router. I have the following data context defined in the router:

```
data: function() { return {
      eventId: this.params._id,
      registrants: Registrants.find({eventIds: {$elemMatch: { $in: [this.params._id]}}}, {sort: {name:1, phone:1, email:1}}),
    }}
```

I want to enable Registrants to be filtered further by user input. In my case, I already have `ReactiveVar` called `filterName` which listen to input text from user. Whenever the input text changed, the `filterName` is updated. ( I followed this answer [ng-repeat + filter like feature in Meteor Blaze/Spacebars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25804879/ng-repeat-filter-like-feature-in-meteor-blaze-spacebars))

Now, I want to add `$and` to the Registrants.find() method to derive new `registrants` data context. How should I do it so that the query is reactive to the `filterName`?

Another approach is by defining Template helper method `filteredRegistrants`. Initially, its value is the same as `return this.registrants`. Whenever `filterName` changed, I would do `return this.registrants.find({name: filterName})`, but somehow I can't invoke `find` from `registrants` cursor, can I? I got `undefined is not  function` error when doing that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`this.registrants` is already a cursor (result of `Registrants.find()`), and not a collection, thus it doesn't have the `find()` method you look for. However, there is nothing wrong with making another query in the helper if the functionality provided by your controller is not enough:

```
Template.registrantsTemplate.helpers({
  filteredRegistrants: function() {
    return Registrants.find(...query...);
  },
});
```

Comment: btw what's the different between that and:
Template.registrantsTemplate.helpers = {
  filteredRegistrants: function() {return Registrants.find(...query...);}
};

Comment: In DiscoverMeteor, no such syntax I saw. Possibly a new syntax to define helper?

Comment: The `Template.name.helpers({...})` and `Template.name.helpername = function() {}` are equivalent. The first one is generally better as it allows you to define several helpers at once, with less code repetitions. As for the `Template.name.helpers = {}` syntax, it is strongly discouraged, as you can cause your helpers to be accidentally removed.